# Swagger UI with Java Rest Service

Tags: java, swagger

I am new to using Swagger documentation. I am using Swagger's annotations on  Java rest service class. Could you please provide some help on the below problem -

My rest method is as below:

```
public String testMethod3(@ApiParam(value = "Mailing address of the user", required = true) @FormParam("address") final String address) {}
```

As you see, I am passing a JSON String parameter - address to my rest method. On the Javascript side, I have the below code to set up the data -

```
var addressMap = {};
addressMap.city = 'SS';
addressMap.zipCode = '98877';
addressMap.state = 'CA';
```

I am now sending this to the rest method by calling `JSON.stringify(addressMap)`.

In Swagger-UI, I am only getting one parameter option to enter. How can I let the user to know that this is a complex object and they need to pass city, zipcode and state values.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing data in a `@FormParam`, you'll need to add a value for each of the fields.  For example, city, zipCode, and state.

But I believe what you really want to do is post the JSON as a HTTP POST method, which case you would remove the `@FormParam` and consume the values into a java object that has the fields in the payload.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I created a Java class and put all those properties and am using that class as a parameter. The swagger UI is showing the parameter type as 'body' now and providing the JSON string. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I would like to know if Swagger supports different request and response Model schema.